# максимальное натуральное число меньше X, которое делится нацело на Y

Tags: любой-язык

Например: найти максимальное натуральное число меньше 5000, которое делится нацело на 39.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Оптимальное решение**

```
5000 // 39 * 39

#4992
```

**Сравнение вариантов решения**

```
def test1():
    num = max(i for i in reversed(range(5000)) if i % 39 == 0)


def test2():
    num = max(filter(lambda x: x % 39 == 0, reversed(range(5000))))


def test3():
    for i in range(5000, 39, -1):
      if not i % 39:
        break


def test4():
    5000 // 39 * 39


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    setup="from __main__ import test1,test2,test3, test4"


    print('test1:',  timeit.timeit('test1()', setup=setup,number=10000))
    print('-' * 25)
    print('test2:',  timeit.timeit('test2()', setup=setup,number=10000))
    print('-' * 25)
    print('test3:',  timeit.timeit('test3()', setup=setup,number=10000))
    print('-' * 25)
    print('test4:',  timeit.timeit('test4()', setup=setup,number=10000))

#test1: 3.1136840023100376
#-------------------------
#test2: 6.391721844673157
#-------------------------
#test3: 0.008747044950723648
#-------------------------
#test4: 0.0008490197360515594
```

**Вывод:** Можно решить гораздо быстрее - без использования циклов, просто основываясь на математических операциях.

Comment: Хороший тест, наглядный :) Скорее всего `reversed(range(5000))` сначала получит все элементы из range, потом их разворачивает, потом фильтрует, поэтому и дольше высчитывает

Comment: Дело в том, что `i for i in reversed(range(5000)) if i % 39 == 0` создаёт некий _список_ из всех делителей. Просто Вы потом с помощью функции `max` берёте максимальное значение из этого списка. В этой задаче глупо проходится по всем 5000 элементам, когда нужно только одно - максимальное.

Comment: А я и не думал над оптимизацией -- первое что пришло в голову, то и написал. На самом деле разница между решениями небольшая для относительно небольших чисел (слышу как где-то плачет сишник :)), будь там значения на порядки большие -- да

Comment: Попробуйте запустить с самым большим известным на сегодняшний день простым числом и вы удивитесь. `4294967293 // 2147483647 * 2147483647`. Первых 3 даже не советую запускать с этим числом)

Comment: Ну это не оптимальное решение, есть в пару строк :)